# um Änderung/um die Änderung

Tags: definite-article

Ich wundere mich, warum in diesem Satz der bestimmte Artikel vor dem Nomen ***Änderung*** ausgelassen wurde.

*Die Geschäftsführung knickte under der Last der Briefe und Anfragen ein, die uns vielleicht nicht in grosser Zahl, aber seit vielen Jahren mit der Bitte **um Änderung** der Zeilennummer zugesandt wurden.*

Es handelt sich doch um eine bestimmte Änderung, und dieses Nomen ist nicht unzählbar, was die Auslassung des Artikels begründen könnte.

Einen schönen Tag noch,
Damian

Answer (score 1):

Der bestimmte Artikel bedeutet "du weißt, von welchem Ding ich spreche". Das ist hier nicht der Fall, es handelt sich nicht um eine bereits bekannte Änderung ("du weißt, von welcher Änderung ich spreche"), sondern um eine, die hier neu eingeführt wird.

Wenn man einen Artikel verwendet, müsste es also "eine Änderung" sein.

Warum ist es auch nicht "eine Änderung"? Das ist auch für mich als Muttersprachler nicht ganz einfach zu beantworten. Es ist jedenfalls nichts, was nur für das Wort "Änderung" gilt. Man kann auch von einer Bitte um Erledigung sprechen, man kann um Rückruf bitten, usw.

Ich denke, es liegt daran, dass das, was nach "Bitte um" bzw. "bitten um" steht, zu einem gewissen Grad etwas Abstraktes ist, nichts Konkretes. [Diese Webseite](https://deutsch-coach.com/der-nullartikel-wann-steht-ein-nomen-ohne-artikel/) schreibt z.B., dass vor abstrakten Begriffen kein Artikel verwendet wird, und gibt als Beispiele an: "für einen guten Text braucht man Wissen und Geduld" und "ich wünsche dir viel Glück und Erfolg".

Comment: Auf mich wirkt es wie Telegrafendeutsch. Also eine Weglassung des Artikels für einen kompakteren Satz. Allerdings konnte ich dafür keine Bestätigung finden.